# AdMob not getting real ads in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am working for **AdMob** in Android and I got success in getting **test ad**. But When I Change My Test UnitId To **Live UnitID** something like this "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx" I am not getting any warning/ error. and also I commented the lines for adding test devices. but still i am not seeing any real adds.

Any Ideas..... Any Better Solution..

**main.xml**

```
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx">
            <!-- I have replaced with my purchased id -->
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  private AdView mAdView;
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
    //banner ad
    mAdView = fragView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
     //InterstitialAd
       mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
      //replaced with my buy ads
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();

        }


    });
```

**NOTE :** I have completed all the payments and necessary details while buying the ads from AdMobs & also the application is in **releasing mode**.

Comment: Do you get any error in your logcat? Please check for error in the logcat.

Comment: Remove `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)`

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in logcat.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have also removed the .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) but still the question is same

Comment: I would also suggest to make the `layout_width` to `match_parent`. `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Please check if that works.

Comment: @ReazMurshed there is no difference either I use match_parent or I use wrap_content I am not getting my ads :(

Comment: I do not see any problem in your code. However, you may check your internet connection and check if there is any adblocker installed in your system.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. Between Thanks for the valuable time and suggestions @ReazMurshed